# change text Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the text using different mouse event but it shows me an error while mn code seems correct!

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>HHH</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 id"text" onmousedown="MouseDown()" onmouseup="Mouseup()">BBB </h1>

  <script>

    function MouseDown() {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="CCC" ;
    }
    
    function Mouseup() {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="AAA" ;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have missing `=` in `h1` tag.. `<h1 id="text" ...>BBB<`/h1>

Comment: It's not correct : check this `id"text"` - this is not valid

Answer (score 1):

It is not, you have:

```
<h1 id"text" onmousedown="MouseDown()" onmouseup="Mouseup()">BBB </h1>
```

there are '=' missing:

```
<h1 id="text" onmousedown="MouseDown()" onmouseup="Mouseup()">BBB </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equals sign when setting the `id`of your `h1`:

`<h1 id="text" onmousedown="MouseDown()" onmouseup="Mouseup()">BBB </h1>`

:)

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `=` when setting the `id` in the HTML so the `id` was never getting set properly.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>HHH</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 id="text" onmousedown="MouseDown()" onmouseup="Mouseup()">BBB </h1>

  <script>

    function MouseDown() {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="CCC" ;
    }
    
    function Mouseup() {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="AAA" ;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```